# Выдает NaN, хотя в тестовом коде все отлично работает. Код один в один

Tags: javascript, nan

```
 window.onload = function () {
      let c = { 'Українська гривня': '1', 'Долар США':'37', 'Євро':'85.60', 'Польський злотий': '7'}; // Устанавливаем курс валют
    
      let val = document.getElementById('input__convert'); // Получаем элемент ввода данных
      let currency1 = document.getElementById('currencySelect1'); // Получаем первый селект
      let currency2 = document.getElementById('currencySelect'); // Получаем второй селект
      let result = document.getElementsByClassName('input__result')[0]; // Получаем поле куда будем писать результат
      function summ() { // Делаем функцию
          let z = 0;
          if(currency1.value === currency2.value){ // Если оба значения в селектах равны
              result.innerText = val.value; // То просто вписываем данные из поля ввода
          } else {
              if(currency1.value != 'Українська гривня'){ // Если не равны рублю, то
                  z = val.value*c[currency1.value]; // Переводим сумму в рубли
                  result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((z/c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Делим на курс и округляем до сотых
              } else { // Если не равны
                  result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((val.value*c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Умножаем на курс и округляем до сотых
              }
          }
      }
      val.oninput = function () { // При вводе данных в поле вызываем функцию.
          summ();
      };
      currency1.onchange = function () { // При смене первого селекта вызываем функцию.
          summ();
      };
      currency2.onchange = function () { // При смене второго селекта вызываем функцию.
          summ();
      }
    }
```

Вот html к нему

```
     <div class="charity__currencies">
                    <a class="converter">Конвертатор</a>
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:140px;">
                        <select id="currencySelect3">
                          <option value="0">У відділенях</option>
                          <option value="1">У відділенях</option>
                          <option value="2">Для карток</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>    
                   <div class="custom-select" id="main__custom-select1" style="width:189px; ">
                        <div class="convert_block_item">
                            <input id="input__convert" type="number" placeholder="0" style="width: 9vw; height: 4.6vh; padding: 0px 2px 2px 10px; font-size: 23px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #c4c4c4; margin: -3vh 40vw 15vh -0.2vw;">
                        <select id="currencySelect1">
                            <option class="currency-button">Польський злотий</option>
                            <option class="currency-button" >Українська гривня</option>
                            <option class="currency-button">Долар США</option>
                            <option class="currency-button">Євро</option>
                            <option class="currency-button">Польський злотий</option>
                        </select>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="convert_block_item">
                            <div class="input__result" style="width: 9vw; height: 4.6vh; padding: 0px 2px 2px 10px; font-size: 23px;  margin-top: 5%; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #c4c4c4; margin: -18.4vh 5vw 15vh 18.4vw; ">0</div>
                                <div class="custom-select" id="main__custom-select" style="width:189px; margin: -87.7px 10px 70px 220px;">
                                    <select id="currencySelect">
                                        <option class="currency-button">Українська гривня</option>
                                        <option class="currency-button">Українська гривня</option>
                                        <option class="currency-button">Долар США</option>
                                        <option class="currency-button">Євро</option>
                                        <option class="currency-button">Польський злотий</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>          
        </main>
```

Comment: Пройдите дебаггером да посмотрите, что в переменных, что не так работает, как ожидалось. Можете ещё в консоль выводить всё подряд, все значения переменных, и потом посмотреть, что в консоли, где не то, что ожидалось.